# How to add the timestamp of the fatal error occurrence to Java fatal error log filename

Tags: java, error-handling, fatal-error, error-logging

### Background

- You can use `java -XX:ErrorFile=/path/to/file` to specify the path of fatal error log file.
- You can use the `-XX:OnError` option to execute a command when an error causes on a Java VM.
- To maintain the fatal error logs, I want to add the timestamp of the fatal error occurrence to the filename.

### Problem

I have tried to set the Java VM option like this:

```bash
java -XX:ErrorFile=/path/to/error.log -XX:OnError="mv /path/to/error.log /path/to/error_store/error_$(date +%F-%H%M%S).log" -jar /path/to/application.jar
```

But when an error occurs on Java VM, the timestamp on the filename is the time of the Java VM's startup, rather than the time of occurrence of the fatal error.

### Question

Is there any way to add the timestamp of the fatal error occurrence to the Java fatal error log filename?

Comment: One way could be to create a simple script that gets executed onerror (onerror takes both command and script) and in this script execute the "mv".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. To make the command expansion works later, you have to pass `$` as a literal (use `\$(...)`) like:

```bash
java -XX:ErrorFile=/path/to/error.log -XX:OnError="mv /path/to/error.log /path/to/error_store/error_\$(date +%F-%H%M%S).log" -jar /path/to/application.jar
```

and when a fatal error occurred, the following command was executed:

```
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /path/to/error.log
#
# -XX:OnError="mv /path/to/error.log /path/to/error_store/error_$(date +%F-%H%M%S).log"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "mv /path/to/error.log /path/to/error_store/error_$(date +%F-%H%M%S).log" ...
Aborted
```